# Relationships between path width and clique size of interval graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, decomposition, treewidth

I faced the following claim on wikiepdia about interval graphs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph):

> The pathwidth of an interval graph is one less than the size of its maximum clique.

I have thought a while about it, but don't come up with any argument/proof why the pathwidth is bounded by the size of the maximum clique-1. Is there a "simple" proof why that is so?
Or is it just the fact, that any clique must be contained in some bag of a tree/path decomposition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is it just the fact, that any clique must be contained in some bag
> of a tree/path decomposition?

To prove the claim one should prove, both, that the pathwidth is at most the maximum clique size - 1 (e.g., by construction), and that there does not exists a clique not contained in a bag as you observed. For interval graphs, a construction proving the first part is pretty much given by their definition.

The second, and perhaps a less obvious part, can be proved, for example, by induction on the max. clique size `k`, and can be also found in many text books, for example, as Lemma 12.3.5 of the 3rd edition of [Diestel's book](https://diestel-graph-theory.com/).

A proof of the lemma for path decomposition goes by induction goes as follows.

Base Step: The claim holds for cliques of size `1` and `2`, which are just vertices and edges, respectively, by the definition. That concludes the base case.

Inductive step: Take a clique `K` of size `k>2`, and consider two cliques `Ku` and `Kv` of size `k-1` obtained by removing vertices `u` and `v`, respectively, from `K`. By the induction hypothesis both `Ku` and `Kv` as well as the edge `uv` are contained in their bags. Now, there are three cases to consider.

If any of these bags are the same then we are done, since then there exists a bag that contains the whole `K`.

If the bag `B` containing `uv` is between the bags containing  `Ku` and `Kv`, by the definition of the path decomposition, `B` also contains all the vertices in the intersection of `Ku` and `Kv`. Therefore `B` contains the whole `K`.

If the bag `B` containing `uv` is NOT between the bags containing  `Ku` and `Kv`. Then either the bag containing  `Ku` is between `B` and the bag containing `Kv`, or the bag containing `Kv`  is between `B` and the bag containing `Ku`. In the former, by the definition of the path decomposition, the bag containing `Ku` also contains `v` and therefore the whole `K`.
In the latter, by the definition of the path decomposition, the bag containing `Kv` also contains `u` and therefore the whole `K`.